# Nueva duda con Timer java android studio. Como usarlos dentro de un bucle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

No hay manera de dar con la solución

Gracias a @JorgeSys, pude resolver una duda con los Timer y afortunadamente he posido solventar esa parte de mi código

Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Tengo un bucle for para las series

Tengo un bucle for para las repeticiones por serie

Dentro de éste bucle, me gustaría tener la duración de los ejercicios y ...

La duración de los descansos entre repeticiones

mi código es más o menos el siguiente

```
//bucle series
for (int i = 0; i < numSeries; i++) {
        //bucle repeticiones
        for (int j = 0; j < numRep; j++) {
            //instancio primer Timer y ejecuto
            timeSerie = new Timer();
            timeSerie.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                    //descontamos 1 a la variable que contiene la duración
                    midTimeSerie--;
                    //calculamos los segundos
                    long ssSerie = midTimeSerie % 60;

                    //si los segundos son igual a 0
                    if (ssSerie == 0) {
                        //la variable coge la duración del ejercicio
                        midTimeSerie = segundosEjer;
                        //cancelamos el Timer actual
                        timeSerie.cancel();
                        //borramos el contenido del TextView
                        txtRelojEjer.setText("");
                    }
                    //si los segundos entan entre 9 y 1
                    else if ((ssSerie < 10) && (ssSerie > 0)) {
                        //escribimos los segundos en el TextView
                        txtRelojEjer.setText("00:0" + ssSerie + "");
                        //reproducimos un sonido
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
                    }
                    else {
                        //escribimos los segundos en el textView
                        txtRelojEjer.setText("00:" + ssSerie + "");
                    }
                }
            //iteramos cada segundo
            },1000);

            midTimeDescanso = segundosDescEjer;
            timeDescanso = new Timer();
            timeDescanso.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                    midTimeDescanso--;
                    long ssDescanso = midTimeDescanso % 60;

                    if (ssDescanso == 0) {
                        midTimeDescanso = segundosDescEjer;
                        timeDescanso.cancel();
                        txtRelojDesc.setText("");
                    }
                    else if ((ssDescanso < 4) && (ssDescanso > 0)) {
                        txtRelojDesc.setText("00:0" + ssDescanso + "");
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
                    }
                    else {
                        txtRelojDesc.setText("00:" + ssDescanso + "");
                    }
                }
            },1000);
        }
    }
```

Pero en lugar de ejecutarme el código del primer Timer, y efectuar el proceso programado para luego pasar al segundo Timer una vez finalizado el primero, me ejecuta los dos Timer a la vez

Alguien podría decirme como hacer un Timer completo correspondiente al ejercicio, y una vez finalizado, pasar al segundo Timer correspondiente al descanso ?

Un vez finalizados los dos Timer volvería al bucle For para seguir con el número de repeticiones.

Al finalizar las repeticiones y sus descansos, saldría del segundo bucle al primero, que volvería a dar otra vuelta mientras siga habiendo series.

---

### editado

Estoy ahora con el siguiente método, en él, más o menos tengo lo que deseo salvo por varios errores que no logro solucionar

1 - no entiendo porqué en el primer timer, al llegar a 9 se detiene

2 - no entiendo porqué en el segurndo timer, al llegar a 50 se detiene

A pesar de tener los timer en dos bucles for con varias iteraciones, solo se efectúa una.

Tampoco logro entrar dentro de los CountDownTimer al intentar depurar el código, pues me salta todo el código que está dentro de todo el timer.

Alguien me puede aclarar mis dudas ?

Los datos del array los importo de otra activity:

```
    serie[0] = txtNombreSerie.setText("Regletas");
    serie[1] = spiNumeroSeries.setSelection(3);
    serie[2] = spiDescansoMSeries.setSelection(3);
    serie[3] = spiDescansoSSeries.setSelection(0);
    serie[4] = spiNumeroRepeticiones.setSelection(5);
    serie[5] = spiTiempoMRepeticiones.setSelection(0);
    serie[6] = spiTiempoSRepeticiones.setSelection(10);
    serie[7] = spiDescansoMRepeticiones.setSelection(0);
    serie[8] = spiDescansoSRepeticiones.setSelection(50);
```

método con los dos bucles y los dos timer

```
private void metodoIniciarSerie(String[] serie) {

    String nombreSerie = serie[0];
    int numSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[1]);
    int numMSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[2]);
    int numSSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[3]);
    int numRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[4]);
    int tiempoMRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[5]);
    int tiempoSRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[6]);
    int numMRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[7]);
    int numSRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[8]);

    int segundosEjer = ((tiempoMRep * 60) + tiempoSRep);
    int segundosDescEjer = ((numMRep * 60) + numSRep);
    int segundosDescSerie = ((numMSeries * 60) + numSSeries);

    int segundosDesSeries = segundosDescSerie - segundosDescEjer;
    contador = segundosEjer;

    long tiempoEntreTicks = 1000; //un segundo
    long duracionTotal = segundosEjer * 1000; //milisegundos

    long duracionTotalD = segundosDescEjer * 1000; //milisegundos

    for (int i = 0; i < numSeries; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < numRep; j++) {

            CountDownTimer ejercicio = new CountDownTimer(duracionTotal, tiempoEntreTicks) {
                public void onTick(long milisegHastaFin) {
                    long segundosPasados = (duracionTotal + milisegHastaFin) / 1000;

                    int m = (int) segundosPasados / 60;
                    int s = (int) segundosPasados % 60;

                    txtDetalleEjer.setText("Trabaja Ejercicio");
                    txtDetalleDesc.setText("");
                    txtRelojEjer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s));
                    if ((m == 0) && (s < 11) && (s > 0)) {
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
                    }
                    else if ((m == 0) && (s == 0)) {
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    txtRelojEjer.setText("00:00");

                    CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(duracionTotalD, tiempoEntreTicks) {
                        public void onTick(long milisegHastaFinD) {
                            long segundosPasadosD = (duracionTotalD + milisegHastaFinD) / 1000;

                            int md = (int) segundosPasadosD / 60;
                            int sd = (int) segundosPasadosD % 60;

                            txtDetalleDesc.setText("Descansamos");
                            txtDetalleEjer.setText("");
                            txtRelojDesc.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", md, sd));

                            if ((md == 0) && (sd == 10)) {
                                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
                            }
                            else if ((md == 0) && (sd < 4) && (sd > 0)) {
                                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
                            }
                            else if ((md == 0) && (sd == 0)) {
                                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
                            }
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            txtRelojDesc.setText("00:00");
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Pues estaba buscando una solución parecida a la que pides. A ver si hay suerte y alguien te responde

Comment: A ver si te sirve mi respuesta @Joseba, gracias

Comment: Pues tomo nota @el.trasgu, la estudiaré con atención. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues nada, después de mucho indagar, probar, invertigar, corregir, borrar, preguntar y experimentar, he dado con una solución que quizás no sea la perfecta pero que me sirve a la perfección

Recurro a la recursividad y elimino los bucles for, dado que los timer son bucles en si mismos

Aprovecho el método on_finish() para llamarse a si mismo, de ésta manera solo se inicia la nueva cuenta regresiva cuando finaliza la anterior

```
private void metodoIniciarSerie(String[] serie) {

    String nombreSerie = serie[0];
    int numSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[1]);
    int numMSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[2]);
    int numSSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[3]);
    int numRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[4]);
    int tiempoMRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[5]);
    int tiempoSRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[6]);
    int numMRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[7]);
    int numSRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[8]);

    int segundosEjer = ((tiempoMRep * 60) + tiempoSRep);
    int segundosDescEjer = ((numMRep * 60) + numSRep);
    int segundosDescSerie = ((numMSeries * 60) + numSSeries);

    int segundosDesSeries = segundosDescSerie - segundosDescEjer;

    long tiempoEntreTicks = 1000; //un segundo
    long duracionTotal = (segundosEjer + 1) * 1000; //milisegundos

    long duracionTotalD = (segundosDescEjer + 1) * 1000; //milisegundos

    contador++;
    txtDetalleNumserie.setText("Entrenamos Serie " + (contadorSeries + 1) + " de " + numSeries);

    Ejercicio = new CountDownTimer(duracionTotal, tiempoEntreTicks) {

        public void onTick(long milisegHastaFin) {

            long segundosPasados = (milisegHastaFin) / 1000;

            BooleanEjercicio = true;

            int m = (int) segundosPasados / 60;
            int s = (int) segundosPasados % 60;

            txtDetalleEjer.setText("Trabaja Ejercicio" + contador + " de " + numRep);
            txtDetalleDesc.setText("");
            txtRelojDesc.setText("");
            txtDetalleDescansoSerie.setText("");
            txtRelojDescansoSerie.setText("");

            txtRelojEjer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s));

            if ((m == 0) && (s < 11) && (s > 0)) {
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
            }
            else if ((m == 0) && (s == 0)) {
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            BooleanEjercicio = false;

            DescansoEjercicio = new CountDownTimer(duracionTotalD, tiempoEntreTicks) {
                public void onTick(long milisegHastaFinD) {

                    long segundosPasadosD = (milisegHastaFinD) / 1000;

                    int md = (int) segundosPasadosD / 60;
                    int sd = (int) segundosPasadosD % 60;

                    BooleanDescansoEjercicio = true;

                    txtDetalleEjer.setText("");
                    txtRelojEjer.setText("");
                    txtDetalleDesc.setText("Descansamos");
                    txtDetalleDescansoSerie.setText("");
                    txtRelojDescansoSerie.setText("");

                    txtRelojDesc.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", md, sd));

                    if ((md == 0) && (sd == 10)) {
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
                    }
                    if ((md == 0) && (sd == 5)) {
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
                    }
                    else if ((md == 0) && (sd < 4) && (sd > 0)) {
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
                    }
                    else if ((md == 0) && (sd == 0)) {
                        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    BooleanDescansoEjercicio = false;
                    if (contador < numRep) {
                        metodoIniciarSerie(serie);
                    }
                    else if (contador == numRep){
                        Ejercicio.cancel();
                        DescansoEjercicio.cancel();
                        metodoDescansoSeries(serie);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();
}


public void metodoDescansoSeries(String[] serie){
    
    String nombreSerie = serie[0];
    int numSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[1]);
    int numMSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[2]);
    int numSSeries = Integer.parseInt(serie[3]);
    int numRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[4]);
    int tiempoMRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[5]);
    int tiempoSRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[6]);
    int numMRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[7]);
    int numSRep = Integer.parseInt(serie[8]);

    int segundosEjer = ((tiempoMRep * 60) + tiempoSRep);
    int segundosDescEjer = ((numMRep * 60) + numSRep);
    int segundosDescSerie = ((numMSeries * 60) + numSSeries);

    int segundosDesSeries = segundosDescSerie - segundosDescEjer + 1;

    long tiempoEntreTicks = 1000; //un segundo
    long duracionTotal = segundosEjer * 1000; //milisegundos

    long duracionTotalD = segundosDesSeries * 1000; //milisegundos

    DescansoSerie = new CountDownTimer(duracionTotalD, tiempoEntreTicks) {
        public void onTick(long milisegHastaFinD) {
            long segundosPasadosD = (milisegHastaFinD) / 1000;

            BooleanDescansoSerie = true;
            contadorSeries++;

            int md = (int) segundosPasadosD / 60;
            int sd = (int) segundosPasadosD % 60;

            txtDetalleEjer.setText("");
            txtRelojEjer.setText("");
            txtDetalleDesc.setText("");
            txtRelojDesc.setText("");
            txtDetalleDescansoSerie.setText("Recuperación entre Series");

            txtRelojDescansoSerie.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", md, sd));

            if ((md == 0) && (sd == 10)) {
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
            }
            else if ((md == 0) && (sd < 4) && (sd > 0)) {
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 80);
            }
            else if ((md == 0) && (sd == 0)) {
                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0, 800);
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            txtRelojDesc.setText("00:00");
            BooleanDescansoSerie = false;
            if (contadorSeries < numSeries) {
                contador = 0;
                metodoIniciarSerie(serie);
            }
            else {
                DescansoSerie.cancel();
                txtRelojEjer.setText("¡¡¡ Muy Buen Trabajo !!!");
                txtRelojDesc.setText("Series Completadas");
                txtRelojDescansoSerie.setText("Enhorabuena");
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```